# mod_rewrite only applying to index

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm attempting to apply some mod_rewrite rules but can only get it applied to my index page.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

changes localhost/site/index.php to just localhost/site/. Going to any other page though though such as localhost/site/login.php the rule doesn't apply and the file extension is still shown.

Also, going to another page from the index and then back to the index readds the extension.

How can this be fixed?

I'm working on localhost using WAMP at the moment if this makes any difference.

Comment: What do you expect to achieve with this set of rules? That's not quite clear.

Comment: @faa The removal of the file extension from URLs.

Comment: ¿Which extensions, php, html?

Comment: php. That's why I've added the RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f part. It works on the index page, but not on others. Is this clearer now?

Comment: But it does not work, so can't be used as a guide. Good luck.

Comment: What? I'm not trying to use it as a guide I'm asking a question as to why this works on the index page and not on others.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23120/discussion-between-michael-n-and-faa)